# EhCacheLock Fail to get write lock on String key, event when key is unique

Tags: ehcache

Instead of getting lock on a my Object.. I am forming a string key by concatenating some string properties from it... and then i am calculating hash using Message Digest 512 algorithm. and i try to get lock on that key...

Now i try to get key for 400 unique keys.. but it fails to get the lock for several keys...

Now according to my understating i should get lock for every key as all are unique..

I have cache configuration as follows

```
Name = "CACHE_LOCK" 
max element in memory = 100000
overflow to disk = false
eternal = false
time to live = 600 secs
time to ideal = 300 secs
```

when i am trying to get the lock i am giving `time_out = 0`

i also am ensuring releasing lock on key.

Comment: Can you share the code that your have written for getting locks and also what is the goal of taking these locks?

Answer (score 0):

bellow method is called when ever i want to get lock on a key...

`public void acquireLock(String key) {
        String hash = generateHash(key);
        Cache cache = getCache();
        try {
            boolean lockAcquired = cache.tryWriteLockOnKey(hash,TIME_OUT);
            if (!lockAcquired)
            {
                throw new Exception(message);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
        Element element = cache.get(hash);
        if (element == null)
        {
            cache.put(new Element(hash,new Object()));
        }
    }`

get cache method returns 
`Cache cache = new Cache(LOCK_CACHE,100000,false,false,600,300);`
which is initialized only once..

the purpose for this is.. 
in concurrent environment.. when a key is form by concatenating different properties of object, these properties identifies the object uniquely.. and there are chances that the different object have same values for these set of properties are in processing at same time.. to avoid this.. i am using ehCache.. so when one tries to get lock on same key(time out is 0) should fail immediately.

(i hope you are getting idea.)